# Odoo append to one2many

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

How do you add new line to one2many?

I have tried

```
car_ids = fields.One2many()
for line in used_car_ids:
    value = {   'make': line.make,
                'type': line.type
            }
    self.car_ids = [(0,0,value)]
```

But it does not append. The `car_ids` will always be filled with only one `used_car_ids` (only the last `used_car_ids`)

How do I append to `one2many`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should try the following:

```
car_ids = fields.One2many()

result = []
for line in used_car_ids:
    result.append((0, 0, {'make': line.make, 'type': line.type}))
self.car_ids = result
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: One thing to add is the field make and type must be decalared in the tree view of you one2many field, or they will be ignored by web client in the other side because he will not figure out where to put the value

Answer (score 0):

Solved, like this.

```
for record in estudiante:
        participante.append(self.env['universidad.participante'].create({
            'primer_nombre_participante':record.primer_nombre,
            'primer_apellido_participante':record.primer_apellido,
            }).id)
    vals['participantes_ids'] = [(6,0,participante)]
```